# What are the performance overheads between logging in to another user account via ssh vs login

Tags: ssh, login, performance, ssh-tunneling, key-authentication

In Gnu/linux systems, I can perform a full local login (i.e. where `logname` returns the same output as `whoami`) by two methods:

**login**:
`sudo login second_user` (prompted for password)

**ssh**:
`ssh second_user@localhost` (prompted for password unless ssh keys have been setup)

I am interested to know if any additional latency or other performance loss occurs by one or the other methods. Any other pros and cons?

I prefer ssh because I know how to set up passwordless / key based login. Is this possible via the other method? I also like that a regular user can perform ssh login without messing with sudoers list (`sudo visudo`).

One further advantage is that a multihop ssh/scp connection can be configured in the client to get to the second login seemingly directly.

Are there methods to obtain similar advantages by the `login` command? Where does it outshine the ssh alternative? Is it acceptable to ssh locally to my 'second user'?

Comment: `login` can only be used locally, whereas `ssh` allows you to work remotely. I see no reason to use `ssh` with `localhost` just to switch users when you already have `login` and `su`.

Comment: What about the following reasons: ssh command is by default allowed without modification to the sudoers list, ssh supports public-key-authentication (passwordless without resorting to -f option).